# "No keyboard for id 0"?

Tags: android

I am new in Android app. development, now I have encountered a strange problem with the Menu button. Here is the thing:

I have two activities, "ActivityOne" and "ActivityTwo", where "ActivityTwo" is the child Activity of "ActivityOne". In both activity, I have defined the menu button options like following:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuItem insertMenuItem = menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_insert);
    insertMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_add);

    MenuItem settingMenuItem = menu.add(0, SETTING_ID, 0, R.string.menu_setting);
    settingMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_settings);

    MenuItem aboutMenuItem = menu.add(0, ABOUT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_about);
    aboutMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_about);

    logPrinter.println("creating menu options...");

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case INSERT_ID:
            doInsert();
            return true;
        case SETTING_ID:
         return true;
        case ABOUT_ID:
         showAbout();
         return true;
    }

    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}
```

In "ActivityOne", when I click the physical Menu button, there is no menu options pop up from screen bottom, when I checked the LogCat console, there are two **warning** messages, which are "**No keyboard for id 0**" and "**Using default keyMap:/system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin**" .

BUT, in "ActivityTwo", the menu button works fine, it shows me those menu options I defined.

Why the menu button does not work in "ActivityOne" ?? What does the warning msg mean???

Comment: ActivityTwo extends ActivityOne?

Comment: No, there is a button in ActivityOne, when user click that button, user will be navigated to ActivityTwo.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["No keyboard for id 0" - what does it mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321706/no-keyboard-for-id-0-what-does-it-mean)

Answer (score 0):

The "no keyboard for id 0" doesn't mean anything.

Now, have you defined `onCreateOptionsMenu` in **both** activities? If not, do it.

Also, use [`onOptionsItemSelected`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)) instead of `onMenuItemSelected`.

Comment: Hi, YES, I have defined onCreateOptionsMenu in both activities. I will use onMenuItemSelected and see if this helps. I will let you know tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I have used onOptionsItemSelected instead of onMenuItemSelected, but it does not help, I still can not have my Menu options pop up when I clicke the physical Menu button... :( Any other suggestions are appreciated.