# "No keyboard for id 0" - what does it mean?

Tags: android, keyboard, warnings, options-menu

Each time my Optionsmenu opens (onCreateOptionsMenu(..) is called),
I get these warnings:

> "No keyboard for id 0"

and

> "Using default keyMap:
>   /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin"

I couldn't find out what they mean, does anyone know ? I didn't like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934014/no-keyboard-for-id-0).

Here's the simple code I'm using:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.optmenu_start, menu);
    return true;
}
```

and the optmenu_start.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:id="@+id/optmenu_prefs"
    android:title="@string/optmenu_prefs"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_menu_prefs"
  />
  <item
    android:id="@+id/optmenu_help"
    android:title="@string/optmenu_help"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_menu_help"
  />
</menu>
```

Comment: Were's your code, do you return to the super? I get these warnings an tbh I ignore them

Comment: I added the code! Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Google's answer is

" The log is normal; it happens the first time a keymap is needed for a device 
in a process.  "

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/477caf755085b108

So therefore if you started Activity2 before Activity1 you would see the warning in Activity2 and not Activity1!

As I said I think a lot of developers get this message and it's just a warning not an error; it can be ignored.

Comment: You're right.. in the next Activity the warning doesn't come up. I'm still not really satisfied but I'll accept that now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As @Blundell said, it's normal.
But it always consumes the first keyPressed event.
Finally, I add this on init:

```
setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

I don't know why, but this warning message never annoys me again.

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub, in my case, it's a customer view, I called `setFocusableInTouchMode(true)` in the constructor of the view.