# onBackPressed not Called Immediately - No Keyboard for id 0 - Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, activity-finish

I am overriding the `onBackPressed` method in my app :

```
public void onBackPressed() {

        System.out.println("BACK PRESSED");
        mp.stop();
        finish();
    }
```

The problem is that the back button needs to be pressed at least three times before this method is called. The first couple of times I get :

```
No Keyboard for id 0
Using Default Keymap : /system/user/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
```

Can anyone spot what is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call `super.onBackPressed();`

for more detail see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6322974/985143)