# no keyboard for ID 0 how can i fix it?

Tags: android

I don't know why this happens because my previous code like this was working but when my activity go on this the application will stop no keyboard for id 0.

```
public class Lesson_p extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
MediaPlayer p, p_sound;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lesson_p);
    p = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.p);
    p_sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.p_sound);

    View p = findViewById(R.id.imageButton_p);
    p.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener)this);

    View p_sound = findViewById(R.id.imageButton_pp);
    p_sound.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener)this);

    Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_bckp);
    back.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener)this);

    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_nxtp);
    next.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener)this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.imageButton_p:
            p.start();
            break;

        case R.id.imageButton_pp:
            p_sound.start();
            break;

        case R.id.button_bckp:
            Intent back = new Intent(this, Example_n.class);
            startActivity(back);
            break;

        case R.id.button_nxtp:
            Intent next = new Intent(this, Example_p.class);
            startActivity(next);
            break;

        }       

}
//@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    p.release();
    p_sound.release();
}
}
```

Comment: you are using same variable for MediaPlayer and View?

Comment: yes because when the imagebutton is click the MediaPlayer will start. .

Answer (score 1):

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321706/no-keyboard-for-id-0-what-does-it-mean). It will give you answer. For getting google answer for this, please click [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/R3yvdVCFsQg).